# Can a CouchDB view index it's own design document

Tags: couchdb

I have a view that looks for all of the "application documents":

```
(function(doc) {
  if (doc.isApplicationDoc === true) {
    return emit(doc.id, null);
  }
});
```

So I can mark config files and make sure they are replicated, etc. But I need to also have the view return the design doc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Answer is yes, but it seems to be undocumented (hence this question/answer):

In the design doc add a property:

```
options: {"include_design" : true}
```